# compare the same time in different time zones in python

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

I want to send an email everyday at a users 7am. For example user 1 is in the America/Los_Angeles time zone.  Customer 2 in America/New_York time zone and would receive an email at 7 their time, but 4am on user 1's time.

My customer object looks like the following:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="customer")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    reminder = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_zone = TimeZoneField()
```

I am able to get the current time in the users time zone with this:

```
    now = datetime.now()
    settingstime_zone = timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
    now = settingstime_zone.localize(datetime.now())
    relative_time = now.astimezone(customer.time_zone)
```

This gives me the correct time for the user relative to their time zone.

How do I now check if it is 7am in that time zone?

Comment: Have you tried to use `relative_time.hour`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough checking `hour` property of datetime object

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> 
>>> customer_time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles'
>>> 
>>> #gets a non naive datetime (utc)
>>> utcnow = datetime.utcnow()
>>> utcnow = utcnow.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
>>> 
>>> #localize current utc with customer_time_zone
>>> relative_time = utcnow.astimezone(timezone(customer_time_zone))
>>> utcnow, relative_time
(datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 4, 5, 41, 2, 294757, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 3, 22, 41, 2, 294757, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>))
>>> relative_time.hour
22
>>> utcnow.hour
5
```